# BottomNavigationBar // Ho to change spacing of the BottomNavigationBarItems

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

EDIT: Solution below

**Goal/Problem:** I'm styling a BottomNavigationBar with a FAB. I'd like to move items 2 and 3 a bit further apart, so they don't hug the FAB so closely. Screenshots and code below.

**Failed solutions:**

- Google showed me lots of post where people wrap the icons in Padding;
  but for me, the labels don't move with the icons.
- I wrapped the BottomNavigationBarItem itself in Padding, but
  the icon list of the BottomNavigationBar doesn't take Padding as a child.
- I cannot use SizedBoxes, as I can only use BottomNavigationBarItem as
  a child in the list
- If I wrap the FAB in Padding, it just moves the FAB, but has no influence on the positioning of the items in the nav bar.
- I cannot wrap the label with Padding as the property just takes strings

**Screenshots:**

No padding:

[image]

With horizontal Padding for demonstration purposes, icons and labels not in sync:

[image]

**Code (with relevant Padding on zero):**

```
BottomNavigationBarItem bottomNavIcon({
  required BuildContext context,
  required Image icon,
  required Image icon_active,
  required String label,
}) {
  return BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 6.h,
        bottom: 3.h,
        left: 0.w
        right: 0.w,
      ),
      child: icon,
    ),
    activeIcon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 6.h,
        bottom: 3.h,
        left: 0.w
        right: 0.w,
          ),
      child: icon_active,
    ),
    label: label,
  );
}
```

**Desperate solution:**
I'm considering placing an invisible icon in the middle and have the onTap method of the navbar do nothing for index 2 ... but that really feels like a hack.

EDIT//The "solution":

I ended up using the hack.Thanks to MSARkrish for giving me this snippet:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
    icon: const SizedBox.shrink(),
    label: "",
  ),
```

Things I needed to do to make it work:

- I added a SizedBox in the list holding the pages; otherwise the icons
  ake the ontap do nothing for index 2:

  ```
         onTap: (index) => index != 2 ? selectPage(index) : () {},
  ```
- I also disabled feedback for the the buttons, otherwise you'd hear a pop, when tapping the invisible button.
- I already had higjhlight colors and splash colors of. I guess they'd cause issues as well, if they were enabled.

God...I hate the BottomNavigationBar widget ... never gonna use that one again... Better to create it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced similar situation in one of our office project. We did this hack to achieve UI like yours.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        icon: const SizedBox.shrink(),
        label: "",
      ),
```

Comment: Heym thanks for answering, but can you elaborate a bit? Doesn't that just make the icon as small as possible? How does that move it (or the label). EDIT: You're using that as an invisible item in the middle?

Comment: OK...I used it as an invisible spacer and it works. I had to do some other things as well. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: @Joe my code will create empty space equal to other navigation bar item. so that floating action button will have equal space like bottom navigation bar item

Comment: It is better to solve the problem from the UI, but when you are going to get the index, you encounter another trouble!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found in the documentation,
represenatation of `SizedBox.shrink()`,

```
const SizedBox.shrink(
{Key? key,
Widget? child}
)
```

**Example:**

```
const SizedBox.shrink({ Key? key, Widget? child })
  : width = 0.0,
    height = 0.0,
    super(key: key, child: child);
```

Comment: This  is just for knowledge purpose, might help someone in future